# Загрузка данных при использовании пакета

Tags: r

Пытаюсь разобраться, как использовать пакет r 'RHRV'  для анализа вариабельности сердечного ритма. Проблема возникла сразу же при чтении быстрого руководства, не получается загрузить пробный файл.
Предварительно осуществляется, как я поняла, создание объектов в глобальном окружении:
 HRVData structure containing the heart beats

```
data("HRVData")
```

HRVData structure storing the results of processing the heart beats: the beats have been filtered, interpolated, ...

```
 data("HRVProcessedData")
```

Создаётся пустой файл с разметкой

```
hrv.data  = CreateHRVData()
```

Преобразуется

```
hrv.data = SetVerbose(hrv.data, TRUE )
```

И вот эта формула вроде должна загрузить данные

```
hrv.data = LoadBeatAscii(hrv.data, "example.beats",
                     RecordPath = "beatsFolder")
```

Возникает ошибка

> ** Loading beats positions for record: example.beats **    Path: beatsFolder     Scale: 1  Error in setwd(RecordPath) : cannot change
>   working directory

Понятно, что не находит файл и директорию (не может сменить директорию), но каким образом вообще подразумевается, что должен найти?

Comment: Функция ожидает передачи существующих путей и соответствующих прав на запись.

Comment: Artem Klevtsov, каким образом передать этой функции данные из объекта в глобальном окружении?

Comment: По имени этого объекта, очевидно.

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov имя объекта "HRVData".    **> hrv.data = LoadBeatAscii(hrv.data, HRVData)
** Loading beats positions for record: 
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'**    При том что мой файл таки же образом загружается     hrv.data = LoadBeatAscii(hrv.data, "rr-2018-09-18_19-32-23.txt")

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите в явном виде значение для `RecordPath`, например следующий фрагмент кода успешно работает:

```
library(RHRV)
hrv.data  = CreateHRVData()
hrv.data = SetVerbose(hrv.data, TRUE )
hrv.data = LoadBeatAscii(hrv.data, "D:\\tmp\\example.beats",RecordPath = "d:\\tmp\\beatsFolder")
```

Каталог d:\tmp\beatsFolder реально создан и имеет права на запись.

Результат работы:

```
Loading beats positions for record: D:\tmp\example.beats 
 Path: d:\tmp\beatsFolder 
 Scale: 1 
 Date:  01 / 01 / 1900 
  Time:  00 : 00 : 00 
 Number of beats: 17360
```

Comment: Sidorin Спасибо, но я всё равно не понимаю, как сделать. Если выполнить ваш код, ошибка "cannot change working directory". Может, потому, что диска "d" у меня нет. Если прописать тот же путь на диск "с", та же самая ошибка. Если создать каталог "t" и в нём папку "beatsFolder", то не находит файл. Который туда никто не клал, понятное дело. С другой стороны, я не знаю, что делает функция LoadBeatAscii(), может, создаёт каталоги и кидает в них что-то из глобального окружения.Но у вас работает, значит, объекты в глобальном окружении лежат в какой-то временной папке, у вас по указанному пути

Comment: Свой файл я могу загрузить, загружается без проблем. потому что я знаю, где он лежит. А с этим демонстрационным проблема.